# Android program to Print Over WifiPrinter

Tags: android, android-wifi

I have an app that consumes an web service. Now I want my android program to connect to a WiFi printer and print the contents in proper format, that it consumed from the web service.Please provide some example for reference.I have already wasted more than a day, So please help me Thanks in advance.

Any help would be highly appreciated.